# results missing a matching value when searching an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm testing a concept to see if it will be suitable for something more complication later.

I have a string and an array. I'd like to search the string to see if it contains any of the values in the array. When it does I'd like it to echo the key and the value of the match from the array. The code I have is this.

```
<?php

$string = '[red,yellow,[blue,[green';
$colour = array ('red','blue','yellow','green');

foreach($colour as $key => $value){

    if(strpos($string,'['.$value)){
            echo $key." ".$value."<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

This, I thought, should return anything which matches "[colour"

I thought this would return the result:

```
0 red
1 blue
3 green
```

It returns

```
1 blue
3 green
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't return a match on [red? 
Something to to with the [ being right at the start of the string?

Comment: Why not just use Linq? Or if you're using Colour's, an Enumerator?

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of Linq. Is it something I can use for this?

Comment: Linq is used for querying through Arrays - like you would a Database - and is available on PHP. Just search *Linq for PHP* and there are plenty of free Frameworks; it allows you to search a string, or integer, through an array and, I think, it supports Objects also.

Comment: `if(strpos($string,'['.$value) !== FALSE){` The first find is in column 0 which === false But FALSE is return only when Nothing is found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strpos` returns string position, red is on position 0
You should change your condition to:

```
if(strpos($string,'['.$value) !== false){
```

as false is returned if there is no match at all